# Illegible embroidery

Tags: translation

I'd like some help figuring out what this embroidery says, if it says anything at all. It's allegedly from China, but I don't have access to the physical object, just a few photos.

Random characters I can sort of pick out:

- Upper right: 豕(?)常
- Upper left (and again somewhere in the middle): 中
- Near the top of both left and middle: 王
- Several on the right (not in a row): 窗, 月, and 有
- Signature: 豈 (and something else)

The level of illegibility is such that I'm not entirely sure I believe that all of these are characters, but someone (somewhere) went to the trouble of sewing it.

[image: Embroidery]

Comment: First vline is a poem : 寻常一样窗前月，才有梅花便不同

Comment: Signature：I Think maybe it's 凯 ，old chinese 敳

Comment: Please remember me to never ask this person to sew my pants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First vline is a poem :寻常一样窗前月，才有梅花便不同